# setting value of a hash key to return value of a function, rails 3 & mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

Can someone explain what's happening here? This is a much simplified example of some weirdness trying to set a hash key in my rails 3.0.11, mongomapper 0.9.0 app.

```
class Foo
  key :a, Hash
  key :b, Hash
end

> foo = Foo.new( :a=>{:timezone=>"Adelaide"}, :b=>{:timezone=>"Azores"} )
> foo.a[:time] = Time.use_zone(foo.a[:timezone]){Time.zone.now}
  => Fri, 11 May 2012 20:20:36 AZOST +00:00 
> foo.a[:time]
  => nil
```

It didn't actually set the hash key to the return value when the timezone from the same hash was used. BUT:

```
> foo.a[:time] = Time.use_zone(foo.b[:timezone]){Time.zone.now}
 => Sat, 12 May 2012 05:51:07 CST +09:30 
> foo.a[:time]
 => Sat, 12 May 2012 05:51:07 CST +09:30
```

Use the b hash timezone and it stores the value. What? I can store the return value of the use_zone block in a local variable and then set the hash key, or use a static string for Timezone etc, but I can't set the key when the block uses the timezone value from the hash itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
foo = Foo.new( :a=>{:timezone=>"Adelaide"}, :b=>{:timezone=>"Azores"} )
Time.use_zone(foo.a[:timezone]){
  foo.a[:time] = Time.zone.now
}
```

Comment: hmm. Setting the key in the Time.use_zone block does indeed work. Can you explain the difference? Why does the assignment work in one case and not the other?